# How to make JOptionPane invisible with minimum code

Tags: java, joptionpane

I want only text "Only I should be visible"  to be visible when I run the program.I dont want to see box, X or OK button to see.Can any one help me with the code or guide me to write.[Please see image for detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RMRR.jpg)

Comment: if you don't want to see that box, don't use JOptionPane.

Comment: JOptionpane is used to create dialogue boxes. If you don't want the box, don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new JFrame with `setUndecorated(true);` and with `setVisible(true);` make visible only when you want. And add in JFrame what you want.